# Retrofit response is null but okHttp Interceptor logger has data

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I have a POST request to get data based on a SessionKey that's generated. If the SessionKey is valid, then there is a response of some Customer data.

The issue I'm facing is that my Retrofit instance is giving me null responses but the okHttp Interceptor logger is returning data, shown in the Logcat.

I obviously have something wrong somewhere, could anyone point me in the right direction?  Hoping it's something simple!

**API Structure**

```
<OrderInfoResponse
  <OrderInfoResult>
    <deliveryAddresses>
      <OrderingDeliveryAddressStruct>
        <deliveryAddressNo>string</deliveryAddressNo>
        <deliveryAddressName>string</deliveryAddressName>
        <pointsOfService>
          <OrderingPointOfServiceStruct>
            <pointOfServiceNo>string</pointOfServiceNo>
            <pointOfServiceName>string</pointOfServiceName>
            <pointOfServiceDescription>string</pointOfServiceDescription>
            <pointOfServiceOrderingGroupNo>string</pointOfServiceOrderingGroupNo>
            <orders>
              <OrderingOrderStruct>
                <orderType>string</orderType>
                <orderDate>date</orderDate>
                <deliveryDate>date</deliveryDate>
                <orderStatus>int</orderStatus>
                <articles>
                  <OrderingArticleStruct>
                    <articleNo>string</articleNo>
                    <articleDescription>string</articleDescription>
                    <articleSize>string</articleSize>
                    <articleTargetQty>int</articleTargetQty>
                    <articleMinQty>int</articleMinQty>
                    <articleMaxQty>int</articleMaxQty>
                    <articleIntervalQty>int</articleIntervalQty>
                  </OrderingArticleStruct>
                </articles>
              </OrderingOrderStruct>                  
          </OrderingPointOfServiceStruct>              
        </pointsOfService>
      </OrderingDeliveryAddressStruct>
    </deliveryAddresses>
    <orderingGroups>
      <OrderingOrderingGroupStruct>
        <orderingGroupNo>string</orderingGroupNo>
        <orderingGroupDescription>string</orderingGroupDescription>
      </OrderingOrderingGroupStruct>
      <OrderingOrderingGroupStruct>
        <orderingGroupNo>string</orderingGroupNo>
        <orderingGroupDescription>string</orderingGroupDescription>
      </OrderingOrderingGroupStruct>
    </orderingGroups>
  </OrderInfoResult>
</OrderInfoResponse>
```

**Sample API Response**

```
{
"deliveryAddresses": {
"OrderingDeliveryAddressStruct": {
  "deliveryAddressNo": 5710030,
  "deliveryAddressName": "UCLH WARDS LINEN",
  "pointsOfService": {
    "OrderingPointOfServiceStruct": {
      "pointOfServiceNo": 3,
      "pointOfServiceName": "E02 S1 THE",
      "pointOfServiceDescription": "E02 STORE 1 THEATRES / LABOUR",
      "pointOfServiceOrderingGroupNo": "571-1",
      "orders": {
        "OrderingOrderStruct": {
          "orderType": "inventory",
          "orderDate": "2023-11-02",
          "deliveryDate": "2023-11-02",
          "orderStatus": 0,
          "articles": {
            "OrderingArticleStruct": {
              "articleNo": 109842,
              "articleDescription": "ESSENTIALS TOP SHEET S",
              "articleSize": "",
              "articleTargetQty": 80,
              "articleMinQty": 0,
              "articleMaxQty": 0,
              "articleIntervalQty": 0
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
},
"orderingGroups": {
 "OrderingOrderingGroupStruct": {
   "orderingGroupNo": "571-1",
   "orderingGroupDescription": "UCLH"
 }
}
}
```

**Data Classes**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class OrderInfo (

  @SerializedName("OrderingOrderInfoResponseStruct" ) var OrderingOrderInfoResponseStruct : 
  OrderingOrderInfoResponseStruct? = OrderingOrderInfoResponseStruct()
)

data class OrderingOrderInfoResponseStruct (
    
  @SerializedName("deliveryAddresses" ) var deliveryAddresses : DeliveryAddresses? = 
  DeliveryAddresses(),
  @SerializedName("orderingGroups"    ) var orderingGroups    : OrderingGroups?    = 
  OrderingGroups()
)

data class DeliveryAddresses (

  @SerializedName("OrderingDeliveryAddressStruct" ) var OrderingDeliveryAddressStruct : 
  OrderingDeliveryAddressStruct? = OrderingDeliveryAddressStruct()    
)

data class OrderingGroups (

  @SerializedName("OrderingOrderingGroupStruct" ) var OrderingOrderingGroupStruct : 
  OrderingOrderingGroupStruct? = OrderingOrderingGroupStruct()    
)

data class OrderingDeliveryAddressStruct (

  @SerializedName("deliveryAddressNo"   ) var deliveryAddressNo   : Int?             = null,
  @SerializedName("deliveryAddressName" ) var deliveryAddressName : String?          = null,
  @SerializedName("pointsOfService"     ) var pointsOfService     : PointsOfService? = 
  PointsOfService()
)

data class OrderingOrderingGroupStruct (

  @SerializedName("orderingGroupNo"          ) var orderingGroupNo          : String? = null,
  @SerializedName("orderingGroupDescription" ) var orderingGroupDescription : String? = null
)

data class OrderingPointOfServiceStruct (

  @SerializedName("pointOfServiceNo"              ) var pointOfServiceNo              : Int?    = 
  null,
  @SerializedName("pointOfServiceName"            ) var pointOfServiceName            : String? = 
  null,
  @SerializedName("pointOfServiceDescription"     ) var pointOfServiceDescription     : String? = 
  null,
  @SerializedName("pointOfServiceOrderingGroupNo" ) var pointOfServiceOrderingGroupNo : String? = 
  null,
  @SerializedName("orders"                        ) var orders                        : Orders? = 
  Orders()
)

data class Orders (

  @SerializedName("OrderingOrderStruct" ) var OrderingOrderStruct : OrderingOrderStruct? = 
  OrderingOrderStruct()
)

data class OrderingOrderStruct (

  @SerializedName("orderType"    ) var orderType    : String?   = null,
  @SerializedName("orderDate"    ) var orderDate    : String?   = null,
  @SerializedName("deliveryDate" ) var deliveryDate : String?   = null,
  @SerializedName("orderStatus"  ) var orderStatus  : Int?      = null,
  @SerializedName("articles"     ) var articles     : Articles? = Articles()    
)

data class Articles (

  @SerializedName("OrderingArticleStruct" ) var OrderingArticleStruct : OrderingArticleStruct? = 
  OrderingArticleStruct()    
)

data class OrderingArticleStruct (

  @SerializedName("articleNo"          ) var articleNo          : Int?    = null,
  @SerializedName("articleDescription" ) var articleDescription : String? = null,
  @SerializedName("articleSize"        ) var articleSize        : String? = null,
  @SerializedName("articleTargetQty"   ) var articleTargetQty   : Int?    = null,
  @SerializedName("articleMinQty"      ) var articleMinQty      : Int?    = null,
  @SerializedName("articleMaxQty"      ) var articleMaxQty      : Int?    = null,
  @SerializedName("articleIntervalQty" ) var articleIntervalQty : Int?    = null
)
```

**Interface**

```
interface OrderInfoInterface {
        @Headers("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8")
        @POST("OrderInfo/")
        suspend fun getOrderInfo(@Body orderInfoRequest: OrderingRequest):
                Response<OrderInfo>

        companion object{
            fun getApi(): OrderInfoInterface? {
                return ApiClient.client?.create(OrderInfoInterface::class.java)
            }
        }
}
```

**Api Client**

```
object ApiClient {
    private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()

    private val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

    private val mOkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(logger)
        .connectTimeout(Duration.ZERO)
        .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build()

    var mRetrofit: Retrofit? = null

    val client: Retrofit?
        get() {
            if (mRetrofit == null) {
                mRetrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(mOkHttpClient)
                    //.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
                    .build()
            }
            return mRetrofit
        }
}
```

**Repository**

```
class DeliveryAddressRepository{

    suspend fun getOrderInfoData(sessionKey: OrderingRequest): Response<OrderInfo>?{
        return OrderInfoInterface.getApi()?.getOrderInfo(sessionKey)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class LoginViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val _sessionKey = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    private val _message = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    private val userRepo = DeliveryAddressRepository()
    val sessionKey: MutableLiveData<String?>
        get() = _sessionKey
    val message: MutableLiveData<String?>
        get() = _message

    val loginResult: MutableLiveData<BaseResponse<OrderInfo>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun getOrderingData(orderSessionKey: OrderingRequest) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {

                val response = userRepo.getOrderInfoData(orderSessionKey)
                if (response?.code() == 200) {
                    loginResult.value = BaseResponse.Success(response.body())
                } else {
                    loginResult.value = BaseResponse.Error(response?.message())
                }
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                loginResult.value = BaseResponse.Error(ex.message)
            }
        }
    }

    fun getSessionKey(loginRequest: LoginRequest) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response = LoginApi.retrofitService.getSessionKey(
                LoginRequest(loginRequest.username, loginRequest.password)
            )
            _sessionKey.value = response.sessionKey
            _message.value = response.message
        }
    }

    fun getDate(): String? {
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMMM, dd, yyyy")
        return LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel call within my Fragment**

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentLoginBinding
    private val sharedViewModel: ParamsViewModel by activityViewModels()

    private val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this)[LoginViewModel::class.java]
    }

    private var username: Editable? = null
    private var password: Editable? = null
    private var sessionKey = ""

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_login, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        sharedViewModel.setAppVersion(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
        sharedViewModel.setFlavor(BuildConfig.FLAVOR)
        binding.apply { viewModel = loginViewModel }
        binding.apply { paramViewModel = sharedViewModel }
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // sets Today's date for login activity
        binding.date.text = loginViewModel.getDate()
        sharedViewModel.setOrderDate(binding.date.text.toString())
        sharedViewModel.setAppVersion(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
        sharedViewModel.setFlavor(BuildConfig.FLAVOR)
        // sets Flavor banner details for login activity
        setFlavorBanner()
        // initiates Firebase remote config options
        fireBaseRemoteConfig()

        with(binding) {
            loginButton.setOnClickListener {
                view
                if (checkUsernamePassword()) {
                    val login = LoginRequest(username.text.toString(), password.text.toString())
                    loginViewModel.getSessionKey(loginRequest = login)
                    val orderInfoRequest = OrderingRequest()
                    loginViewModel.getOrderingData(orderInfoRequest)
                    binding.lifecycleOwner?.let { it1 ->
                        loginViewModel.loginResult.observe(it1) {
                            when (it) {
                                is BaseResponse.Loading -> {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                        activity,
                                        "Loading Data",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                    ).show()
                                }

                                is BaseResponse.Success -> {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                        activity,                                            
                                        it.data?.OrderingOrderInfoResponseStruct.toString(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                    ).show()
                                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_landingPageFragment)
                                }

                                is BaseResponse.Error -> {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                        activity,
                                        it.msg,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                    ).show()
                                }
                            }
                        }   


    private fun setFlavorBanner() {
        val flavorBanner = binding.flavorBanner
        // sets banner text
        if (sharedViewModel.flavor.value == "dev") {
            flavorBanner.text = resources.getString(R.string.devFlavorText)
        }
        // hides banner if PROD application
        if (sharedViewModel.flavor.value == "prod") {
            flavorBanner.isVisible = false;
        }
        // sets banner text and banner color
        if (sharedViewModel.flavor.value == "preProd") {
            flavorBanner.text = resources.getString(R.string.testFlavorText)
            flavorBanner.run {
                setBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        context,
                        R.color.elis_orange
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }

    private fun fireBaseRemoteConfig() {
        // sets the Firebase Remote Config settings
        val remoteConfig: FirebaseRemoteConfig = Firebase.remoteConfig
        val configSettings = remoteConfigSettings {
            minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds = 3600
        }
        remoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings)
        remoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(R.xml.remote_config_defaults)
        // Fetches remote config parameters setup in the Firebase console.
        remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
    }

    private fun checkUsernamePassword(): Boolean {

        username = binding.username.text
        password = binding.password.text

        return if (TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.username.text) ||
            TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.password.text)
        ) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Username or Password cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
            false
        } else
            true
    }
```

**Logcat entry**
[image]

Comment: It looks like you are using wrong model as your response root, you should use `OrderingOrderInfoResponseStruct` instead of  `OrderInfo`. You dont get any error because you have all data nullable and moshi did not found the names you wanted and discarded entries that do not match your model. If you are sure some of the data must came in response, then it is better to use nonnullable values and let moshi crash in such cases (or use it like that for tests to see crash logs when response cannot be properly parsed)

Comment: @V-master thank you for the quick response! I did try changing this previously and get the following error returned "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $.deliveryAddresses"

Comment: It means where it tries to parse - they expected a json object but got an array or json array. check your response.

Comment: @Mahi What am i checking, for example? The response does not give me any indication as to what is wrong. I've given all the info i can think of in my question. okHttp returns a response with the data i'm expecting but Retrofit returns nulls?

Comment: The error says it: when trying to parse field `deliveryAddresses` it got array ( [square brackets] ) instead of object ( {curly braces} ). As you can see in screenshot you attached the response is different from one you attached to question as a text, you need to make corrections to your model. Array can be parsed to `java.util.List` of objects

Comment: btw. you are using `@SerializedName` that is from gson library and does not work with moshi - moshi will use variable names as they are. In case you need to parse variable under different name you should use [@Json annotation](https://github.com/square/moshi#custom-field-names-with-json)

Comment: @V-master i think the penny has dropped. I think i know where i'm going wrong with the array etc. Thank you! I an't wait to test my theory out tomorrow now! Thank you for your help! Also, thanks for the heads-up with the gson/moshi, it's appreciated.